# What's the best technology for connecting from linux to MS SQL Server using python? ODBC?

Tags: python

By best, I mean most-common, easiest to setup, free.  Performance doesn't matter.

Comment: You may find this topic helpful: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289978/whats-the-simplest-way-to-access-mssql-with-python-or-ironpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289978/whats-the-simplest-way-to-access-mssql-with-python-or-ironpython)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289978/whats-the-simplest-way-to-access-mssql-with-python-or-ironpython

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate, I think.  The "from linux" in my question and the "or ironpython" in the other question makes these questions different.   I need something I know will work on linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided that pyodbc was the best fit.  Very simple, stable, supported:
http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/

Answer (score 2):

[pymssql](http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/), the simple MS SQL Python extension module.

Answer (score 1):

[FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning Python myself, but it seems like there are Python libraries that look more like Java JDBC drivers.  Google found these articles about [SQLObject](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-pythonsqlo/) and [cx_Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/devlin-python-oracle.html).