# How to make a connection to the MS SQL database using the python script

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the simplest way to access mssql with python or ironpython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289978/whats-the-simplest-way-to-access-mssql-with-python-or-ironpython)

I would like  to make a connection to the MS SQL database using the python script 2.6 version.

The scrip is running on the same system i.e. on Windows Server 2008. After connecting to the data base i want to read and write data on to the table.

Any help would be most appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: check the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289978/whats-the-simplest-way-to-access-mssql-with-python-or-ironpython