# Can we acess SQL Server data from Iron Python Script File if so how I m trying this following code?

Tags: silverlight, ironpython-studio

Can we access SQL Server data from Iron Python script file if so how I m trying this following code ?

```
import sys

import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows")
from System.Windows import Application

import pypyodbc
constr="DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Data Source=SERVERName;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True"
cnxn=pypyodbc.connect(constr)

da=cnxn.cursor("Select Ename from tbl_Empployee where Emp_id=1",cn)
da.execute();

for row in da.fetchall():
    for field in row: 
        Application.Current.RootVisual.FindName("textBox2").Text = field
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .net native types, see: [What's the simplest way to access mssql with python or ironpython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289978/whats-the-simplest-way-to-access-mssql-with-python-or-ironpython)

your code could look like this:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
from System.Data.SqlClient import SqlConnection, SqlParameter

conn_string = 'data source=SRG3SERVER; initial catalog=vijaykumarDB; trusted_connection=True'
connection = SqlConnection(conn_string)
connection.Open()
command = connection.CreateCommand()
command.CommandText = 'Select Ename from tbl_Empployee where Emp_id=@employeeId'
command.Parameters.Add(SqlParameter('@employeeId', 1))

reader = command.ExecuteReader()
while reader.Read():
    print reader['Ename']

connection.Close()
```

Comment: my using microsoft sql server after retriving data how to assign to user control